# Getting a PhoneGap Plugin to Work

Tags: javascript, html, plugins, cordova

I have zero experience with mobile applications, but the company I work for is developing an application that we want to be able to port to both iOS and Android without too much overhead involved. Thus, we decided to use PhoneGap.

I still know very little about it. I learn by practicing, and what I'm trying to do is get the basics set up so that I can start doing my own thing, building, testing, and adding onto the project.

I currently have it synced with Adobe Build. I am able to execute the "phonegap run android" command and then rebuild it on AB. Then, I use a barcode scanner app on my Android tablet to get the link to the download, after which I can test it out.

My Question:

I am trying to set up a simple application to test out the Compass plugin. I am using this tutorial from the PhoneGap blog that I found here:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_compass_compass.md.html

There is a section where they give a "Full Example", with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Compass Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // The watch id references the current `watchHeading`
    var watchID = null;

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        startWatch();
    }

    // Start watching the compass
    //
    function startWatch() {

        // Update compass every 3 seconds
        var options = { frequency: 3000 };

        watchID = navigator.compass.watchHeading(onSuccess, onError, options);
    }

    // Stop watching the compass
    //
    function stopWatch() {
        if (watchID) {
            navigator.compass.clearWatch(watchID);
            watchID = null;
        }
    }

    // onSuccess: Get the current heading
    //
    function onSuccess(heading) {
        var element = document.getElementById('heading');
        element.innerHTML = 'Heading: ' + heading.magneticHeading;
    }

    // onError: Failed to get the heading
    //
    function onError(compassError) {
        alert('Compass error: ' + compassError.code);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="heading">Waiting for heading...</div>
    <button onclick="startWatch();">Start Watching</button>
    <button onclick="stopWatch();">Stop Watching</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

The project that was created via the "phonegap create my-app" gave me a familiar environment with folders for CSS, JS, images, and some other folders which I am unfamiliar with.

When I built the contents of the folder I was able to successfully see the blinking "PhoneGap Ready" bar, so it appears that Cordova is working correctly.

I replaced the index.html file with the code above. When I built and ran the app, I saw the PhoneGap logo, then that disappeared and the application started. I see some text that says "Waiting for heading...", as well as two buttons: (1) Start Watching and (2) Stop Watching.

Nothing happens when I click the buttons. I know this question is really niche, so if I have been unable to provide specific enough details to determine the solution, then I would really appreciate an explanation on how plugins are supposed to work.

Do I need to include a line of code specific to Android or iOS that tells the device that I want access to the Compass? Do you know of any examples of working projects that I could try to load myself?

Thanks,
Joe Majewski

Update:

As per a request, here is my config.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.helloworld" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <description>
        Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        PhoneGap Team
    </author>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon gap:platform="webos" src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" />
    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May you post your AndroidManifest.xml and config.xml files?

They should look like this:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="us.custom4.calculodecuadro"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<supports-screens 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:resizeable="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**config.xml**

```
<cordova>

<plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker" />
<plugin name="File" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils" />
<plugin name="FileTransfer" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer" />
<plugin name="Notification" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
<plugin name="Storage" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage" />
<plugin name="Battery" value="org.apache.cordova.BatteryListener" />
<plugin name="Device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device" />


<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> 

<access origin=".*"/>

<log level="DEBUG"/>
<preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="false" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<plugins>
    <plugin name="App" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
    <plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
    <plugin name="Device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
    <plugin name="Accelerometer" value="org.apache.cordova.AccelListener"/>
    <plugin name="Compass" value="org.apache.cordova.CompassListener"/>
    <plugin name="Media" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler"/>
    <plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>
    <plugin name="Contacts" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager"/>
    <plugin name="File" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils"/>
    <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
    <plugin name="Notification" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
    <plugin name="Storage" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>
    <plugin name="Temperature" value="org.apache.cordova.TempListener"/>
    <plugin name="FileTransfer" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer"/>
    <plugin name="Capture" value="org.apache.cordova.Capture"/>
    <plugin name="Battery" value="org.apache.cordova.BatteryListener"/>
    <plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
    <plugin name="Echo" value="org.apache.cordova.Echo" />
</plugins>
```

Comment: I will edit the question with that info. I can only find the config.xml file. I haven't made any changes to the file; is that something I need to do to enable Compass use? Where can I find the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: I cannot tell you where to find it as you're using a tool I haven't. Yes you have to enable access to your device's hardware in those files.

Comment: Have a look to my answer. On iOS it should be something similar.

Comment: I noticed that the Cordova JS file being linked in from that script was not found in my files. I did some searching online and I found an older version (1.7.0), and after adding that to my project, re-building, and running the app, it is appearing to work now. The "Waiting for head..." text was replaced by a number 0 - 360 corresponding to the degrees for the direction the device is pointing. I still don't know what the Start and Stop buttons do, as I don't see anything change when clicked. I'll credit you for the answer if nothing else comes up after a while.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think I'm starting to get this. :)